# Command line error

Tags: rendering, command-line

I'm trying to run Blender from the command line but I'm getting the following results. Obviously, it didn't render. It worked for me with Blender 2.68, but quit as soon as I put 2.69 on the computer. I navigated to the folder where blender.exe is found, and still couldn't get it to work.

```
./blender -b ../CSANM454/blender_tests/caustics_test.blend --engine CYCLES -F PNG -x 1 -o //theFrame
Read new prefs: /users/ugrad/[my username]/.config/blender/2.70/config/userpref.blend
found bundled python: /users/ugrad/[my username]/blender-2.70-linux-glibc211-x86_64/2.70/python
read blend: /users/ugrad/[my username]/blender-2.70-linux-glibc211-x86_64/../CSANM454/blender_tests/caustics_test.blend

Blender quit
```

I'm trying to run this command through PuTTY. Any idea why it will no longer work?

Comment: Whats the error? - you aren't passing a command to render and its not rendering. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Looks like I need to add the -f option. Thanks for the tip